# is redux toolkit slower than normal redux reducers?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I have seen this post

What is difference between Redux and Redux toolkit?
The Redux Toolkit generates the new state from the direct changes to the old state.
... The reducers that are written with immer are 2 to 3 times slower than a normal
Redux reducer.
Here is an example of a Reducer function that uses the state
as immutable and one which makes changes directly to the state.3 Feb 2020

is that true?

Comment: Did you forget to include your example?

Comment: There are multiple questions here. Is it slower? Sometimes. Does the difference matter? Maybe occasionally, likely rarely. Is the tradeoff worth it? Usually. Is it *faster*? Sometimes. A reductionist take on "performance" is almost never the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Immer documents its expected performance behavior here:

https://immerjs.github.io/immer/performance/

In practice, the perf differences are not generally meaningful. Reducers are almost never the perf bottleneck in a typical React+Redux app. The cost of updating the UI is significantly greater.